# Variables not appearing in RStudio global environment after debug mode

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I am running into an issue saving variables in my global environment after exiting debug mode in RStudio. When I hit an error that pushes RStudio into debug mode, I'll enter "Q" for the "Browse[1]>" prompt and exit debug mode. After that, if I try to save a variable (for example "a <- 2") then I don't see it appear in my global environment. It *does* get saved (if I call "a" in the console it will return "2"), but I don't see the variable listed in the Global environment (there is no "a" variable listed in my environment window. What's going on? Do I need to quit debug mode differently?

Comment: It's been almost three years, but I have a similar issue!